# Reading data from columnized textfile with empty data fields using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am attempting to create a new excel file (will be imported into a database) by looking up data from my old database in a text file and including the information, if any.

The challenge that I am facing right now is that the text file from which I need to gather the new information is not uniformly filled. It consists of "columns" seperated by multiple spaces, however not all "cells" (for lack of a better word) are filled with data. When using the built-in excel funtion to import text files this is not problem and empty columns are added. The only issue with this approach is that the text file consists of over 1.2 million lines of data and excel maxes out at about 1.04 million rows.

For this reason I would prefer to leave it as a text file but I am unsure how to properly split the data and keep it in the same structure so that I can predictably fill an array with the data of the current row.

So my question is sort of two parted, what would be a good approach to splitting the text in the file using vba, taking into account that simply delimiting on spaces is not an option (I think)?
Or should I convert the text file into an excel with two worksheets to contain all the data and  just search this?

If the second approach is preferabel, would it be possible to use the From Text function, found under the Get External Data tab, in my VBA script or would I need to write a similair funtion myself? Manual actions should if possible only consist of activating the macro.

I have added a sample of the text file that I have to gather the new information from.

[image: Sample of text file]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new field in the database, one that you fill to indicate the item has been processed. Then, I would use VBA to connect to the database rather than use a text file. VBA could automatically fill the Excel file and set the "processed" field to "Yes". That way you know which records in the database are in your file.

I would also use VBA to upload the data to the new database - maybe immediately?

In other words, I guess I am asking why you use a text file in the first place?

Comment: The text file is kind of a must. This is contains the updated data for the items in my database I don't have that information in any other format.

Comment: In what format is your database? I'd suggest not to put the database information in any file, but to access the database directly. If you absolutely have to use the text file, I guess you can process a line of data and delete it from the text file... but if you can avoid that, all the better.

Comment: Thank you for thinking along with me. The database is an SQL database. I have found a solution to my problem. I found a table describing the structure of the textfile. So now i simply read out every line check my database for that item, if it exists I copy the data from that line in the textfile to a new excel. This excel can then be evaluated before importing into the new databse. The reason for not directly uploading the data to the new database is because some items will have to be deleted as they no longer available or are no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using:

```
 Dim prodCodeFabr As String
 Dim artLevPath As String
 Dim CurrentLine As String
 artLevPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

 Open the file containing new data
    Open artLevPath For Input As #1

    'Loop over each line in the dataset
    Do Until EOF(1)

        Module1.code

        'Retrieve the productcode from the currentline of the dataset and check if it is included in the database artikel table, if it is pass the informatie to the excel
        Line Input #1, CurrentLine

        prodCodeFabr = Right(CurrentLine, Len(CurrentLine) - 165)
        prodCodeFabr = Left(prodCodeFabr, 20)

        'Check if artikel on the line in the dataset is in ridder
        If (tblArtikel.Locate("TYPE_NR", prodCodeFabr) Or tblArtikel.Locate("EXTERN_VERKOOPNR", prodCodeFabr) Or tblArtikel.Locate("FABR_NR", prodCodeFabr)) = True Then


            'if artikel is in the old database parse the line to create an array with a known structure
            tmp = ReadLine(CurrentLine, Counter, volgLetter)

        End If
    Loop

    Close #1
```

ReadLine is filled with lines similair to

```
        prodCodeFabr = Right(CurrentLine, Len(CurrentLine) - 165)
        prodCodeFabr = Left(prodCodeFabr, 20)
```

it simply "cuts" the information out of the line at predefined locations